# How to populate an html select with another html select dynamically with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, select

I want to take the selected value of this select:

```
  <td>
        <select name="colourone" id="firstcolour">
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Navy">Navy</option>
        <option value="Royal Blue">Royal Blue</option>
        <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
        <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
        <option value="Emerald Green">Emerald Green</option>
        <option value="Maroon">Maroon</option>
        <option value="White">White</option>
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
        </select>
```

And use jQuery to add the selected value from that select and add it to another select so that it dynamically populates.

This is what I tried:

```
$(document).add(function(){
    $('#firstcolour').change(function(){
        $('#colouroption').append($("<option>", {"value": listone_value, "text":    listone_value})).insertAfter($('#blksize'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

```
$('#firstcolour').change(function() {
  var option = $("<option>", {
    "value": $(this).val(),
    "text": $(this).find("option:selected").text()
  });
  $('#colouroption').append(option);
});
```

this will add the new option as the last one.

If you want to add the newly created option as the first one, then use `prepend()`

Comment: var listone_value = $('#firstcolour').find('option:selected').text();        Maybe this is what the problem is? because when I use what you had it just doesn't work at all.